# How to get DotNet Core ApplicationName set by Environment Variable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

According to the .NET Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#application-key-name), I should be able to set the application name using an environment variable.

> Environment variable: ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONKEY

I am not seeing this to be the case.  I added the `WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey` setting to the `Program.cs` but I am still unable to override it with an environment variable.

```
    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_")
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) => { builder.ClearProviders(); })
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .PreferHostingUrls(true)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, "CustomApplicationName")
            .Build();
    }
```

In `startup.cs` I am only seeing "CustomApplicationName" rather than the environment variable.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Log.Information($"Startup of application {hostingEnvironment.ApplicationName} in Environment Mode {hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}");
    }
}
```

I have tried using double underscore in the environment variable name as well.

I am running on Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, the correct environment variable name is `ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONNAME`, and it is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#host-configuration-values).  However, it will not work, even as of .NET Core 3.1.  There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11085) that describes the details of this bug, but essentially, the code inside the `UseStartup<>()` method sets **ApplicationName** back to its default value, which is the name of the assembly.

Even if you could override it back using the `UseSetting()` method, I wouldn't do it, based on the warnings in the discussion thread at [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7315).  The safest bet for now seems to use your own separate environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is something that the documentation "invented" and isn't actually implemented.

ASP.NET Core is hosted on github. I [did a search](https://github.com/search?q=ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONKEY&type=Code). The only place where `ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONKEY` shows up is in the documentation itself. The only issue/PR where it comes up is https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/pull/7493 which is the commit that added this environment variable to the docs and includes this insightful statement:

> Did I just make up ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONKEY? Is that a thing?

Comment: I think you are correct.  Nice find.   The string doesn't seem to appear in any actual Github code and there are only 3 instances of it appearing in Google (at the moment).

Comment: Indeed, the correct variable is ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONNAME